# Heroku INSERT command denied to user

Tags: mysql, laravel, heroku

I deployed my laravel application with database to heroku

It was success but when I tried to register a new user

I get this error

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1142 INSERT command denied to user

I am using laravel 8.x, mysql as database

I ran heroku run bash  and mysql command to connect to mysql

but mysql command is not recognized in heroku terminal

how do I solve this issue?

Comment: [GRANT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/grant.html) needed permissions on needed object(s) to user's account.

Comment: @Akina mysql does not work in heroku bash. How do I achieve that

Comment: @Akina mysql does not work in heroku bash. How do I achieve that

Comment: It doesn't matter where the client is executed in.

Comment: @Akina when I try to run mysql command on heroku bash I get command not recognized error.

Comment: Alter TERMINAL codepage. Not client or connection settings.

Comment: @Akina sorry I dont understand how to alter terminal